# Using std::variant in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17

Attempting to build an application on Mac using `std::variant` to heavily simplify a problem. Xcode doesn't seem to have the header for these installed (The Xcode 10 beta does).

How could I add the necessary header to Xcode so that it can be built on devices other than my own (i.e. without forcing the header into the Xcode application)?

edit: the language dialect is already set to c++17 and the header is also not found in experimental/variant

Comment: Try including `experimental/variant` and set your Xcode to use C++17 in project properties tab.

Comment: The language is already set to C++17 and it still does not find the header under the experimental path (nor is variant in the experimental folder)

Comment: Seems like the XCode 9 compiler is based on LLVM 5, while XCode 10 is based on LLVM 6 (released Mar 2018). The set of features is different. Perhaps you can use boost::variant while waiting for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

from Xcode 10 onwards variant is supported